# Sheet Set value the make copy of spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to produce several spreadsheets from a model,

```js
function copySpreadSheet() {
  var filesName = ['file1', 'file2', '...']
  filesName.forEach(function copySpreadSheet(fileName) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('model_ID');
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('REF');
    sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(fileName);
    var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder_ID")
    DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy(fileName, destFolder);
    
  }); 
}
```

The problem is that the changes i made in the sheet at range 'A2' are not applied in the copies.
Any suggestions pls?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### The code within the `forEach()` loop is executed asynchronously

This means that your sheets might get all copied before the setting of a new value has taken place.

You avoid this by implementing [SpreadsheetApp.flush())](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) and [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds) requests that force the code to wait.

Sample:

```js
function copySpreadSheet() {
  var filesName = ['file1', 'file2', '...']
  filesName.forEach(function copySpreadSheet(fileName) {
   Logger.log(fileName);
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('model_ID');
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('REF');
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(fileName);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder_ID")
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy(fileName, destFolder);
    
  }); 
}
```